# 403 error on Client.executeQuery()

Tags: c#, wcf, office365, http-status-code-403

I am trying to retrieve some information from a Office 365 site. I am getting a inconsistent 403 error on executeQuery call. This happens irregularly and is solved by IISReset. Please help.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(Constants.SP_URL);
            {
                SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in Constants.SP_SERVICE_PASS.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
                var cred = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Constants.SP_SERVICE_ACC, passWord); ;
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Constants.SP_SERVICE_ACC, passWord);


                    Web web = clientContext.Web;

                    string docLibraryName = Constants.SP_PUBLISHED_LIB;
                    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(docLibraryName);
                    clientContext.Load(list);
                    **clientContext.ExecuteQuery();**
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to get a client context and load your data.This authenticate you against SP Online in office 365. I do not know how would you say i reset my IIS. This is not applicable unless you connect to a local SP instance.

```
private void AutheticateO365(string url, string password, string userName)
{
   Context = new ClientContext(url);
   var passWord = new SecureString();
   foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
   Context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, passWord);
   var web = Context.Web;
   Context.Load(web);
   Context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```